# Why this doesn't display the value of variable in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
 {!! Form::select('type', array('' => 'type',
'Workshop' => 'Workshop','Social' => 'Social',
'Other' => 'Other'),
$value=$type,$options = array('class' => 'form-control'))!!}
```

There for the `$value`, it should display the value of variable. Even though, it contains the value, it display type which is the default value for drop down. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this way :

```
{!! Form::select('type', array('' => 'type','Workshop' => 'Workshop','Social' => 'Social','Other' => 'Other',$value,$options = array('class' => 'form-control'))!!}
```